# How to remove indentation from datagrid highlighted row?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am wondering how to remove this indentation at `DataGrid` from selected (highlighted) row.

[image]

I tried to set margin and padding to zero, i have tried many other things but without success.

Please, does somebody have some idea what to do?

Here is crucial part of my xaml:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Height="200" Width="1000" Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding RecordsToShow}" Margin="10,359,329,10">
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static Colors.Transparent}"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static Colors.Transparent}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="UNCHECKED">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="CHECKED">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="UNRESOLVED_MISTAKE">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="UFO">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Turquoise" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Obrázek" Width="*">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ProductPhoto}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Číslo" Binding="{Binding NomenclatureCode}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Název" Binding="{Binding NomenclatureDescription}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Velikost" Binding="{Binding SizeCode}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Počet" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Chyba" Binding="{Binding Mistakes}" Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seting the `RowHeaderWidth` property to `0` should get rid of the indentation completely:

```
<DataGrid ... RowHeaderWidth="0">
```

You may also want to specify a negative left- and right margin in your `Style` to remove the indentation of the selected row:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="UNCHECKED">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="CHECKED">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="UNRESOLVED_MISTAKE">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="UFO">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Turquoise" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-3 0 -3 0"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Excellent, both advices are exactly i was looking for. Firstly i tried to set RowHeaderWith in trigger property, but i did not see it, then i asked here. But second advice helped me too :-) thanks